# What should I do to get the accented character in MySql？

Tags: mysql

I used **select char(148);** to get the accented character **'ö'** , but the result was hexadecimal **0x94** , how to get the wanted character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CHAR` function also supports a optional charset parameter.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char

> CHAR(N,... [USING charset_name])

I'm not sure in which charset the number 148 corresponds the character you mention `ö` ( it's not that number in utf-8, the default charset as of MySQL 8 ), but you should be able to provide the charset from this [list here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-charsets.html) to the `CHAR` function to get the results you expect.

Comment: I apperciate your patience sincerely. I tried the 'using utf8mb4' clause, the number 148 returned 'NULL'. But 65 returned 'A'. If I don't add the optional clause, the output will be hexadecimal of whatever number in 'char()' . Actually, I encountered the problem when I read the book 'Learning SQL, third edition'. And I've written an email to the author. I hope to get his answer quickly. Anyway, thanks a lot, you encourage me to seek the answers and to help others as much as I can.